# Searching for data in a console App!

Tags: c#

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections;
namespace ReadFiles
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)

        {
            StreamReader objstream = new StreamReader("c:\\documents and settings\\btallos\\desktop\\Company.txt");
            string sLine ="";
            ArrayList arrText = new ArrayList();

                while (sLine != null)
                {
                    sLine = objstream.ReadLine();
                    if (sLine != null)
                        arrText.Add(sLine);
                }

            objstream.Close();
            foreach (string sOutput in arrText)
            Console.WriteLine(sOutput);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

I wrote a console app that displays information from a local file on my desktop and displays the content within the file. I was wondering how can I create a function that can search for keywords and only display the words, I want it to search for?

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Please post examples of input and expected output. It is not clear from your description what you are after.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the generic List instead of an ArrayList. You can then use the [Where](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803.aspx) method and provide a string to search for, like this:

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines("filename").ToList(); // Read all lines and cast it to a List<string>
var matches = lines.Where(x => x == "query");
foerach(var match in matches)
{
    Console.WriteLine(match);
}
```

This will find all items equal to your query.

You can easily expand this to search for items containing your query by switching `x => x == "query"` to `x => x.Contains("query")`

Comment: In addition to this, one can also use StartsWith and EndsWith methods for better control over the results.

Comment: Or, if you'd rather not read the entire file into memory:  `var matches = File.ReadLines("filename").Where(x => x == "query");`

Answer (score 0):

I would start with [File.ReadAllText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143369.aspx) and the push on to [System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.aspx)

Comment: Every time I hear about Regular Expressions, I can't help but remember this [XKCD comic](http://xkcd.com/208/). :)

Answer (score 0):

Fuzzy requirements, but this is the solution from what I understood:

```
  var keywords = new string[] {"some", "keywords"};
  var foundKeywords = File.ReadAllLines("filename").
    SelectMany(line => keywords.Where(keyword => line.Contains(keyword))).
    Distinct();
```

The criteria can be improved (with a regular expression, for example). Currently it will also return you the keywords that are substrings of other words.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to try to put this content into a database - And then search for the content I want it to display.

```
* ZIP Codes
* Area Codes
* City Name
* State Name
* Two digit State Code
* City Type
* City Alias Abbrev.
* County Name
* State FIPS
* County FIPS
* Time Zone
* Daylight Savings Indicator
* Number of Businesses
* Q1 Payroll
* Annual Payroll
* Number of Employees
* Employment Flag
* County Growth Rate
```

Comment: Instead of putting this as answer, please edit your question and add the details.

Answer (score 0):

You could figure out how you want to highlight the text you want to search in a console app (say be pre/postpending $$search text$$).  Open each document and run a regex replace.  If that returns a string length different than original, you have matches.  If you don't want to show the whole document, I would get 50 characters before, and 50 after for example, but that might take a bit more work.  Crude, but simple.